# How to add a view in image editor of adobe creative sdk?

Tags: android, adobe, adobecreativesdk, image-editor

I want to add a banner below the tools in the image editor component of adobe creative sdk.

I have searched online but it seems they only let you customize of the options of the image editor like colors and values etc.

If anyone here know any way to do it please let me know

THanks Guys

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible via the Creative SDK APIs.

Altering the Image Editor UI beyond the scope of what the Creative SDK APIs make possible isn't allowed, and apps doing so won't be approved for Production IDs.

[You can read more about Creative SDK app submission guidelines on the Creative SDK developer portal](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/submissionguidelines/index.html).